# Suggest me a distro "beetwen debian and ubuntu"?

Tags: distribution-choice, distributions

I need to install a linux distribution; i like the distro debian-like. I used to use ubuntu, i tryied the new version..it seems to me to be a fake of Mac OS...something just to let you say: yeee i have a dock too...:(

Can you suggest me some distributions that are similar to the previous ubuntu versions?

I mean professional and user friendly, not just eyecandy that use 30% CPU to open a window...

Comment: Just sharing a link.  Don't know much about [Debian Med](http://www.debian.org/devel/debian-med/) but you may find it interesting.

Comment: This has an actual answer:  Try out an alternative desktop environment.  KDE (which is more windows-like), Xfce, Enlightenment....  There's a lot out there, and most of them are not Mac-like.  And they work on Ubuntu, so you don't have to install a whole new OS - just install the new one, log out, and switch which one to log in using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it isn't mac saying, "Look we have a desktop like GNOME!".

[openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/en/) is nice and comes in several flavours like KDE (windows *like* with several add-ons), gnome (like mac...), and lxde/xfce (lighweight distros).

It uses an RPM based package management system with [zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aZypper_features) (libzypp).

[YaST](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal%3aYaST) is also awesome in openSUSE. It makes system management very user-friendly.

If you don't like what you see, build your own with [suseStudio](http://susestudio.com/)!

Not sure if they are like 'previous ubuntu' versions. But the open source world is always advancing/changing and it doesn't hurt to adapt and learn new things.